# How to transform an image to remove meaning(objects/context) but retain other (lower-level) features?

Tags: image-processing, fft

(First time here.. trying my best to explain the problem)

I have an image-viewing dataset. There, I use an individual's eye position to crop out a series of images which correspond to wherever they looked on the image. For reasons, I want to make these frames unrecognizable and remove "meaning" from them, while retaining some other features such as orientation and spatial frequency content, RGB distributions, and between-frame correlation (by this, I mean that if two frames look similar before the transform, they should look similar after the transform). The orientation and spatial frequency content is most important to us, but it would be nice to preserve as much as possible.

What I tried so far is "phase-scrambling" - where we take the 2D FFT of the image (RGB, separately) and add (identical) random noise to the phase component, and take the inverse transform. The result (as far as I understand it) preserves the orientation and spatial frequency content, captures some RGB information (when visually comparing the original and transformed frames), and also between-frame correlations (when looking at frames that are shifted by only a few pixels, the transformed frames look very similar). A big limitation is that the locality of the features is not preserved here. [A demo of individual frames - original on top, phase-scrambled at bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzduR.jpg)
The result looks qualitatively decent, but I'm wondering about better solutions to this problem.